# Quarkus - loading fixture data for tests programatically

Tags: testing, quarkus, fixtures

Does anyone know an efficient way to load fixture data for testing an application written in Quarkus using the entities defined in the application?

I know I could use a .sql file to load this data with hibernate (quarkus.hibernate-orm.sql-load-script). This has to be pure sql code though and is not as maintainable as persisting entity object data.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I use [Instancio](https://www.instancio.org/getting-started/#instancio-core) like this:

```
Instancio.ofList(MyEntity.class)
  .size(100)
  .ignore(field(MyEntity::getId()))
  .create()
  .foreach(MyEntity::persist());
```

Instancio is a great library for generating test data and it should be in your testing arsenal.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
@Singleton
public class TestPopulator {

    @Inject
    Session session;

    @Inject
    UserTransaction transaction;
    
    public void initData(@Observes StartupEvent event) throws Exception {
        transaction.begin();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            MyEntity entity = new MyEntity(i);
            session.persist(entity);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

where `TestPopulator` would be somewhere in `src/test/java` to ensure that it only gets included in tests